# drupal change default node settings

Tags: php, drupal

I am learning drupal and doing this tutorial type of thing and I am just stuck here for like 45 minutes and it's driving me crazy......

basically the tutorial type thing I am reading has an exercise that requires to make the checkbox for "create new revision" checked by default (http://drupal.org/node/1576500). And I have been at this for like an hour and just cannot figure it out.

If some one could help me figure this out it would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new node type or edit an existing one, the edit page at /admin/structure/types/manage/[node_type] has a menu in the bottom section.  Open "Publishing options" and check "Create new revision".  That checkbox will now be checked by default when creating new nodes of that type.

Comment: Definitely. Drupal's got a lot of features but the learning curve is going up quickly with every version.